# how to call multiple image with opencv

Tags: opencv

I am using this line of code to call my image in python 
(img = cv2.imread("frame12160.jpg") 
but I can just call one image once a time  how can I call multiple images every time and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read one image at a time using `cv2.imread()`. If you want to read in multiple images, try using the `os` package and save the images into a list:

```
import cv2
import os
my_images = []
os.chdir('/home/stephen/Desktop/images/')
for path in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
         img = cv2.imread(path)
         my_images.append(img)
```